# PHP echo form submit

Tags: php, forms, submit, echo

I would like to know how to make form "submit" also a  `echo("<a href='.signalservice/subscription.php?customer_id=" . $result->customer->id . "'>Create subscription for this customer</a>");`

My code is :

```
 if ($result->success) {
echo '
<form action="//tradeitsimple.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=fc50a4fa89bccc3ad26bb4c71&amp;id=b9d9e2fe10" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
<label for="mce-EMAIL">You will receive signals through email, please leave your email address!</label>
<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">


';


    echo("Success! Customer ID: " . $result->customer->id . "<br/>");
    echo("<a href='.signalservice/subscription.php?customer_id=" . $result->customer->id . "'>Create subscription for this customer</a>");
} else {
    echo("Validation errors:<br/>");
    foreach (($result->errors->deepAll()) as $error) {
        echo("- " . $error->message . "<br/>");
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to to both, submit the form and redirect i recommand to use jQuery. Add an id to your link and prevent the default action with `preventDefault()`. Then you can submit the form with an AJAX request and after the form is posted you can redirect to the link's `src`. Try this:

```
 if ($result->success) {
echo '
<form action="//tradeitsimple.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=fc50a4fa89bccc3ad26bb4c71&amp;id=b9d9e2fe10" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
<label for="mce-EMAIL">You will receive signals through email, please leave your email address!</label>
<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
';


    echo("Success! Customer ID: " . $result->customer->id . "<br/>");
    echo("<a id=\"myLinkId\" href='.signalservice/subscription.php?customer_id=" . $result->customer->id . "'>Create subscription for this customer</a>");
} else {
    echo("Validation errors:<br/>");
    foreach (($result->errors->deepAll()) as $error) {
        echo("- " . $error->message . "<br/>");
    }
}
?>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on('click','#myLinkId',function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link        = $(this);
        var form        = $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form');
        var dataArray   = form.serializeArray();

        $.post(form.attr('action'), dataArray, function(){

            window.location.href=link.attr('src');

        });
    });
</script>
```